# Работа с пользовательскими данными

Tags: html, get

Мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь вводил какой-то текст в поле текста и нажимал на кнопку, то переходил на другую страницу и в другом текстовом поле появлялся тот же текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method=post  action="step2.php">
<textarea name=xx></textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

А в файле step2.php

```
<form method=post>
<textarea name=xx> <?=$_POST['xx']?></textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Пост можно поменять на гет.